# regarding creation of table with multiple columns in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to create a table consisting of  multiple columns(7 to 8 columns). Most of the examples I saw is with 2 or 3 columns.And how can I scroll the page horizontally(e.g if there are 8 columns,I shall be able to see all the column by just scrolling).when i am trying to add more than three columns its is not getting accommodated in the emulator screen.
Can anyone provide me a sample code?

Please help

thanks

Comment: In order to scroll it horizontally you need to put your view inside <HorizontalScrollView> in the XML layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView for it and have any number of tables. http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html You can specify the number of columns using android:numColumns="2" inside the GridView element. It will be scrollable when the number of columns is more than width of the device.